# How to validate overlapping no in java

Tags: java

I Have dynamically render row. WE have fields like FROM TO.

```
For eg: From     TO
        2        10,
        2        3,
        8        12
```

It cannot accept this combination row.. That means no number should be overlapping.

```
For eg: From     TO
        2        10,
        0        1,
        11       12
```

This combination is allowed.the row may also increased.

I need need to write a validation for this overlapping.
Can any 1 help to solve this problem.

This is the code, wat i tried,

```
List<AppHrVacationAccrualRuleDefinition> a = new ArrayList<AppHrVacationAccrualRuleDefinition>();
List<AppHrVacationAccrualRuleDefinition> b = new ArrayList<AppHrVacationAccrualRuleDefinition>();

a=ruleDefinition;
b=ruleDefinition;

int count = 0;
int k = 1;

for (int l = 0; l < a.size(); l++)
{
    for (int j = k; j < b.size(); j++)
    {
        if (((a.get(l).getStartValue().equals(b.get(j).getEndValue()) || 
                a.get(l).getStartValue() < b.get(j).getEndValue())) && 
                ((b.get(j).getStartValue().equals(a.get(l).getEndValue())
                || b.get(j).getStartValue() < a.get(l).getEndValue())))
        {
            System.out.println("INNN*************");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("count********" + count);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have written to start solving this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping? you mean that every number must be different?

Comment: I have pasted the code wat i tried.. This is working for 2 rows, the list of value increase to 3 then this condition fails.

Comment: Your implementation look fine otherwise, but your overlaps() implementation is a bit weird. Change it to `a.high >= b.low && a.low <= b.high`

Answer (score 7):

Your algorithm is `O(N^2)`; in fact you can easily do this in `O(N log N)` as follows.

- Sort intervals by their upper bound: `O(N log N)`
- For-each interval: `O(N)`

  - If this interval's lower bound is lower than the previous interval's upper bound, then there's overlap
- If you didn't find any overlap in the for-each, then there's no overlap.

So for the two testcases you've given, this is how it'll work:

```
Input:
  (2, 10), (2, 3), (8, 12)

Sorted by upper bound:
  (2, 3), (2, 10), (8, 12)
      |____|
      FOUND OVERLAP!

Input:
  (2, 10), (0, 1), (11, 12)

Sorted by upper bound:
  (0, 1), (2, 10), (11, 12)
      |____|   |____|
        OK!      OK!        NO OVERLAP!
```

To do this in Java, you'd want to use:

- `class Interval implements` [`Comparable<Interval>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- `List<Interval>` and then [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

  - Or you can use [`TreeSet<Interval>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little test case:

```
package playground.tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import playground.Range;

public class NonoverlappingRangeListsTest extends TestCase {
    public void testOverlap() throws Exception {
        assertFalse(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(6, 7)));
        assertTrue(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(3, 7)));
        assertTrue(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(7, 3)));
        assertTrue(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(-1, 0)));
        assertTrue(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(5, 6)));
        assertTrue(new Range(0, 5).overlaps(new Range(2, 3)));
    }

    public void testIsNonoverlappingList() throws Exception {
        List<Range> list = new ArrayList<Range>();
        assertTrue(Range.isNonoverlapping(list));
        list.add(new Range(0, 5));
        list.add(new Range(6, 7));
        assertTrue(Range.isNonoverlapping(list));
        list.add(new Range(2, 3));
        assertFalse(Range.isNonoverlapping(list));

    }
}
```

And a class that passes the test:

```
package playground;

import java.util.List;

public class Range {

    private final int from;

    private final int to;

    public Range(int from, int to) {
        this.from = Math.min(from, to);
        this.to = Math.max(from, to);
    }

    public boolean overlaps(Range that) {
        return this.from <= that.to && that.from <= this.to;
    }

    public static boolean isNonoverlapping(List<Range> ranges) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.size(); i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ranges.size(); j++)
                if (ranges.get(i).overlaps(ranges.get(j)))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
foreach i1 in interval
   foreach i2 in interval
      if (i1 != i2)
         if (overlap(i1, i2))
            return true;
```

clear?

Comment: You need something more like "if (overlap(i1, i2)) return Invalid;"

Answer (score 1):

You can create and boolean array with the size of the max number you can get, say `bool mem[MAX_SIZE]`, then for each of those rows, you will set the according TO-FROM range in that boolean array to `true`, true meaning that this position is already occupied.

Something like this:

```
void mark(int to, int from){
  for(int i=to; i<= from; i++)
     mem[i] = true; //falls into an already-existing interval
}
```

then, when you want to process the rows, as your example states, a sufficient condition to signal an illegal operation is that either TO or FROM overlaps an already processed interval

```
boolean isOverlap(int to, int from){
   if(mem[to] == true || mem[from] == true)
       return true;
}
```

If your MAX_SIZE is relatively big, then the array will get bigger, but it does save you processing time over some nested for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so:

```
public boolean overlap(List<Interval> intervals) {
    int countMinusOne = intervals.size() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < countMinusOne; i++) {
        Interval first = intervals.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j <= countMinusOne; j++) {
            Interval second = intervals.get(j);

            if (second.getStart() <= first.getEnd() &&
                second.getEnd() >= first.getStart()) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This assumes that the start of an interval is always smaller than the end of an interval. It does as little checks as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lot of the answers here are pretty spot-on. There is, however, a well understood data-structure for this that might be of use to you: [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 0):

Set numbers = new HashSet()

while more numbers
{
   read next number; if not exist in numbers continue else fail validation;
}

(or I completly misunderstood the question...)